# How to get the current time in Google spreadsheet using script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There is an option to write a script and bind it to a trigger. The question is, how to get the current time in the script body?

```
function myFunction() {

  var currentTime = // <<???

}
```

Comment: In what format?  What are you using it for?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

use the JavaScript `Date()` object.  There are a number of ways to get the time, date, timestamps, etc from the object.  ([Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp))

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.getTime();  // Number of ms since Jan 1, 1970

  // OR:

  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString(); // "12:35 PM", for instance
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I considered with timezone in my Google Docs like this:

```
timezone = "GMT+" + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); // "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

[my script for Google docs](https://github.com/andyclub/Google-Docs/blob/master/Insert%20Date.gs)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object provided by javascript. It's not unique or special to Google's scripting environment.

Answer (score 7):

Anyone who says that getting the current time in Google Sheets is not unique to Google's scripting environment obviously has never used Google Apps Script.

That being said, do you want to return current time as to what? The script user's timezone? The script owner's timezone?

The script timezone is set in the Script Editor, by the script owner. But different authorized users of the script can set timezone for the spreadsheet they are using from `File/Spreadsheet settings` menu of Google Sheets.

I guess you want the first option. You can use the built in function to get the spreadsheet timezone, and then use the `Utilities` class to format date.

```
var timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm")
```

Alternatively, get the timezone offset from UTC time using Javascript's date method, format the timezone, and pass it into `Utilities.formatDate()`.

This requires one minor adjustment though. The offset returned by `getTimezoneOffset()` runs contradictory to how we often think of timezone. If the offset is positive, the local timezone is behind UTC, like US timezones. If the offset is negative, the local timezone is ahead UTC, like Asia/Bangkok, Australian Eastern Standard Time etc.

```
const now = new Date();
// getTimezoneOffset returns the offset in minutes, so we have to divide it by 60 to get the hour offset.
const offset = now.getTimezoneOffset() / 60
// Change the sign of the offset and format it
const timeZone = "GMT+" + offset * (-1) 
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(now, timeZone, 'EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` object is used to work with dates and times.

Date objects are created with `new Date()`.

```
var date= new Date();

 function myFunction() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        Logger.log(currentTime);
    }
```

Comment: what's the purpose to add an answer that doesn't bring anything new ?