# Using Now function in GAS Function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a GAS function in order to make sure that the date does not change whenever my spreadsheet is changed. The function works when I return new Date() but says that Now() is not defined.

```
fucntion timestamp(){
return new Now()
}
```

Comment: You should use the Date() object of JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182020/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-google-spreadsheet-using-script-editor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current time in Google spreadsheet using script editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182020/how-to-get-the-current-time-in-google-spreadsheet-using-script-editor)